# How can I make external monitor to work on safe mode?

Tags: windows-7, thinkpad, safe-mode

My Machine is now working only on safe mode
I'm using windows 7 64-bit pro edition
I want my external monitor to work, is there any way doing it?
I'm using Lenovo Thinkpad W-530

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the external monitor connected, boot into safe mode, then **disable the internal monitor in device manager**. Reboot (with the external monitor still connected).

If ths does not work, disable also the display adapter and reboot.

Now you should now have a display on the external monitor. [See same post here](http://www.computing.net/answers/windows-xp/how-to-make-laptop-boot-to-external-monitor/191776.html)